# ~/.bashrc does not recognize export

Tags: bash, osx, bashrc

This is probably the weirdest thing you've ever seen. But it's true. I'm on macOS, and want to install devKitARM. After installing Git, the guide told me to show the program where the binaries are. It told me to execute:

```
echo "export DEVKITPRO=/opt/devkitpro" >> ~/.bashrc
echo "export DEVKITARM=/opt/devkitpro/devkitARM" >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

However, when I do this, it gives me

```
export: Command not found.
export: Command not found.
export: Command not found.
```

I looked in the `~/.bashrc` and realized that there was already an `export PATH` command in there, probably for some system function. However, this was not being recognized the entire time. Can someone help?

Comment: Are you sure that you’re running bash?

Comment: I should be... I'm pretty sure it's pre-installed on macOS, and other bash commands work. Also, oddly, the man page for it exists, but the command itself not.

Comment: (1) “it's pre-installed” — proves nothing. (2) “other bash commands work” — what do you mean?  Are you talking about thing like `cat`, `cp` and `ls`?  These are not bash commands.  What happens if you just type `export` at your command prompt? (3) “the man page for it exists” — the man page for what? (4) “the command itself not” — what do you mean? Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your currently running shell is the (TENEX) C shell, which does not have an `export` command.  You cannot `source` a Bourne Again or POSIX shell script in the C shells.  The C shell syntax is different to the Bourne/POSIX shell syntax.

Adding these environment variables to your interactive shell involves the C shell's `setenv` command.  Having this done automatically for login shells involves the C shell's `~/.login` script.

[The manual installation instructions](https://devkitpro.org/wiki/Getting_Started/devkitARM) actually simply say "Add these variables in your execution environment".  The Bourne Again shell is just a "for instance".  Obviously, if you aren't using the Bourne Again shell, which you clearly are not, then you do what is appropriate for your actual choice of shell.

Comment: See also this SO question about how to change login shell on macOS: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/453236/how-to-set-my-default-shell-on-mac

Comment: Thanks! I figured out I had to run the terminal as bash, then source the /.bashrc